# android sysout and log

Tags: android

Whether i should should use sysout or Log.x en-order to debug an android project. I think both are writing to file. Me, commonly using sysout and use filter in LogCat to get it easily. But most of the tutorials and sample i see it is mainly using log.x

What is its basic difference? any link or tutorial for that? Which is better to use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai Labeeb Brother, You can refer this from andbook which may download from the following site using your facebook account itself
http://www.docstoc.com/docs/57705463/Android

if downloaded that book, pls go through the page number 45 and 46. this will give clear idea brother.

refer those pages of the book ,in the following image brother
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a good practice to avoid using sysout (even when using standard java development).

Using the Log object gives you support for tags and priorities.
Logcat has built-in filtering capabilities on tags and priorities.

There's also a performance gain when using the Log object properly, as writing a lot of info to the output stream can be an expensive operation. 
The Log object also exposes an isLoggable that allows for selective logging (depending on tag and priority).

Information on viewing the log output can be found here : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Information on the Log object can be in the Android Developer Reference under android.util.Log

Some options for viewing your log output on your android phone can be fuond with the following Google query : android logcat viewer phone